# Closing one highly received question as a dupe of another highly received, later question?

Tags: discussion

There's a really annoying issue in trying to do input in C++ (really, trying to do input in C++ itself is an annoying issue) that many new users come across so I find myself closing a lot of questions as dupes. Usually, I close them as a dupe of [cin and getline skipping input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10553597/2069064) (May 2012, question is +26, accepted answer is +55). But recently in the comments of a question I just dupe-hammered, a user mentioned [Why does std::getline() skip input after a formatted extraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21567291/2069064) (Feb 2014, question is +33, self-answer is +36).

They both clearly address the same issue, but this second question is more concise and the answer, in my opinion, more adequately explains the problem and how to fix it.

Is it OK to close the former as a duplicate of the latter?

Comment: That works for me.

Comment: Yes, it is okay and even recommended: favor answers over the date/time of the posted questions.